# Using final keyword for reference and use it in timer, referenced object can't be deleted?

Tags: java, timer, final

I have a question about using timer with a final reference.
Like the code below, `ammoBody` is declared in `myFunction` and it goes out of scope once the function finish running. But the timer will use this  reference so I'm sure that's still there. Then after the timer finish running, what happens to this `final Ammo ammoBody` ?

EDIT:

Sorry, I think I didn't finish my question. This matters because I wonder when later I made `myAmmo` itself out of scope.(I want to kill it). Is that doable? Since there's this `final Ammo ammoBody` always pointing to it. Or `final Ammo ammoBody` does get deleted once the timer done its job. But does this mean, before that happen, I'm not able to delete `myAmmo`?

```
void myFunction(){

    final Ammo ammoBody = myAmmo; //myAmmo is declared outside  


    Timer deleteAmmoTimer = new Timer();
    // the ammo disappear after few seconds
    deleteAmmoTimer .schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (ammoBody != null) {
                doSomethingTo(ammoBody);

            }
        }
    }, 3 * 1000);
```

}

Comment: The variable goes out of scope, but that has no effect on the object that it references.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you have a look at the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ammoBody` variable will be garbage-collected sometime after the `TimerTask` is.

You can change the `myammo` variable without it adversely affecting the `ammoBody` variable.

Comment: Do you mean I can't delete `myAmmo`? Because something is referencing to it?

Comment: `myAmmo` is a reference, not an object. You can clear the reference but the object will live until all of its references go away, which will not be until after the `TimerTask` is stopped.

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I wanna make sure. Thanks